# How to get application root in react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native

I have a project running in ios.
In my project I want to get absolute url of application.
How can I do this?

```
<WebView
 style={{flex:1}}
 source={{ uri:'../src/html/privacy-policy.html'}} />
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this URL?

Comment: I want to load local file to webview, but when<WebView
       
       style={{flex:1}}      
       source={{ uri:'../src/html/privacy-policy.html'}}
       
       
           />
 I write in this way it gets error. It only works when I gave absolute url

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load local html file in react native you should `require` it

```
<WebView
  style={{flex:1}}
  source={require('../src/html/privacy-policy.html')} />
```

sample html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

   <h1>My First Heading</h1>

   <p>My first paragraph.</p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I tried this I can see html as a string with it's tages.
How can I force html to display correctly?

Comment: can you add your html to question because it is should render automatically without showing tags i''l update answer with example

Comment: The html is very simple 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>asdsdsadsa</h1>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Maybe I should do some folder configurations? I didn't understand why it is not working. Or maybe the react-native version is matter?

Comment: no folder  configuration require and i don't know what version you use but it should work in latest version i tested it